# How to delete class attributes defined outside the __init__ from within __init__?

Tags: python, attributes

`class` `Foo`:

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        del self.foo

    def foo(self):
        pass
```

when instantiated `raise`s `AttributeError: Foo instance has no attribute 'foo'`. Deriving `Foo` from `object` (`class Foo(object)`) `raise`s `AttributeError: 'Foo' object attribute 'foo' is read-only`. Using `delattr(self, "foo")` doesn't help either.

Doing the following doesn't delete the attribute from `Foo`'s instance either:

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = None
        del self.foo

    def foo(self):
        pass

>>> Foo().foo
<bound method Foo.foo of <__main__.Foo instance at 0x00000000042EA248>>
```

**Objective:**

I basically want to totally remove/or make inaccessible certain attributes from the instance of a given `class` provide some conditions are met.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = None   # This masks the foo method on the instance `self`
    def foo(self):
        pass

foo = Foo()
print(foo.foo)
# None
print(foo.foo())
# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

However, are you sure you want this design? Perhaps instead define subclasses of `Foo`, and select the right class *before* instantiation...

```
class Base(object):
    def common_method(self): pass

class Foo(Base):
    def foo(self): pass

class AltFoo(Base):
    def alt(self): pass

def make_foo():
    if somecondition:
        return Foo()
    eles:
        return AltFoo()
```

Comment: what if the condition's proposition is derived from an attribute of `self`, i.e. the instance of `Foo` itself?

Comment: Can you give an example? Why not pass the info upon which the condition is based to `make_foo`?

Comment: `types = self.type();
if "library" in types and "lone" in types: del.addItem`. The info is actually self-possessed(oops) and calculated within. Currently I have added `type` to `Base`, then essentially replacing `somecondition` with `"qux" in Base().type()`. Wasteful, maybe, but works.

Comment: *OOP instead of "oops"

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that what you're trying to delete is a method, and methods aren't stored on the instance, they're stored on the class.

So your instance `Foo()` doesn't really have an attribute `foo`.  When you do `Foo().foo`, it finds the `foo` on `Foo`.  So there's nothing to delete on `self`, because the attribute isn't on `self`.

If the class defines a method (or any class attribute) `foo`, there's no way to delete it from an individual instance.  The best you could do would be to use some `__getattribute__` hackery to make it raise an exception.  However, this would introduce a performance hit to every attribute access on every `Foo` instance.

Why do you feel the need to do this?

Answer (score 0):

`foo` isn't an attribute of `Foo` instances, it's an attribute of the `Foo` *class* object.

When you use `Foo().foo`, that line creates a new `Foo` instance, then looks up the name `foo` in the instance. The instance doesn't have a `foo` attribute, so the lookup falls back to the class of the instance, which is `Foo`. That's how names bound in a class block work; they create attributes on the class object, and only indirectly affect the instance through this lookup fallback mechanism. That's exactly how normal method calls work - for a class with 10 methods and a thousand instances we don't want 10,000 method objects!

The *only* way you'll get an attribute on the instance is if some code assigns it *directly* on the instance after it has a reference to the instance, as in the typical `self.name = something` pattern in `__init__`.

So there's no way to use `del` to get rid of `foo` from just one instance; you could `del Foo.foo` to delete it from the class, but that would affect *all* instances. That isn't something that makes any sense to put in the `__init__` method for initialising one particular instance.

You could mask it by defining a `foo` on `self`; then that one takes priority and it can vary from instance to instance (but if you ever `del` it then `foo` starts going back to the class `foo` again. Or you could use the generic attribute access hooks like `__getattribute__` to do some checks and sometimes act as if `foo` doesn't exist. Or you could get rid of `foo` as a class attribute entirely, and add it to each instance when you *do* want it there rather than removing it when you don't.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
class Foo(object):
 def __init__(self):
  setattr(self,"foo", None)
 def foo(self):
  pass

>>> Foo().foo
>>>
```